# Typeclass methods with "dummy" argument

Tags: haskell

The typeclass `Data. Bits` has a method `isSigned :: a -> Bool` that returns `True` if the type of the argument is a signed type. The docs explicitly say that the argument is ignored. There are other such methods like that in the typeclass; there are also other typeclasses that have such methods. My question: why this design choice? The value depends only on the type, so why not just:

```hs
isSigned :: Bool
```

As a follow-up: suppose I had a custom typeclass with a nullary method `method :: Bool`. Would there be any reason to change it and do as `Data.Bits` does, that is, `method :: a -> Bool`?

Comment: There isn't one value of `isSigned`; there is one value *per instance*, and you need some way of indicating which instance to use.

Comment: In the past w went though several solutions for this problem. Initially it was `method::a->Bool` to be called as `method (undefined::T)`, knowing that the value did not matter. Then we used `method::Proxy a->Bool` to be called as `method (Proxy::Proxy T)` to make things more explicit. We had a few more vanrianta (like `Tagged a Bool`). Nowadays we use modern extensions and `method::Bool` to be called as `method @T` like the answer below explains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the argument is ignored at *runtime*, but the type of the argument is used during compilation to select the correct instance of `isSigned` to use at runtime.

---

Without the argument, there is no way to determine *which* instance should be used to resolve the value of something like `isSigned :: Bool`.

```
> class Foo a where isSigned :: Bool

<interactive>:1:19: error:
    • Could not deduce (Foo a0)
      from the context: Foo a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   isSigned :: forall a. Foo a => Bool
        at <interactive>:1:19-34
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘isSigned’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method: isSigned :: forall a. Foo a => Bool
      In the class declaration for ‘Foo’
```

If you enable the `TypeApplications` and `AllowAmbiguousTypes` extensions, you could do something like this:

```
class Foo a where
    isSigned :: Bool

instance Foo Int where
    isSigned = True

instance Foo Char where
    isSigned = False
```

Using `isSigned` alone would still be an error, but you could use `isSigned @Int` or `isSigned @Char` to get the specific value for a given type.

Back to standard Haskell, we need some way to select which instance's `isSigned` value is needed, and we do that by defining a function whose argument type ties it to a particular instance. The *value* of the argument is ignored, but the *type* is used during type-checking and compilation to select the correct instance.

Comment: Maybe it would also be interesting to mention the ["visible forall in types of terms" proposal](https://ghc-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/proposals/0281-visible-forall.html) which [will be part of GHC 9.10](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/9.10.1-notes.html). That removes the need for ambiguous types and enforces that the type is explicitly applied.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this in context. My (probably confused) understanding would be that the member could be defined as `isSigned :: forall a -> Bool`, then one could "call" `isSigned Int` instead of having to provide an `Int` value as an argument to a function?

Comment: That's right. I think the biggest advantages are that it is local to this one function (and even to a single type variable) and that GHC could potentially produce better error messages if you forget to apply the type argument. I don't actually know what the messages look like, but I personally hate "ambiguous type variable" errors.

Comment: Actually, I see now that Section 1.2 of the proposal explains the motivation using the `sizeOf :: forall a -> Sized a => Int` function and shows how the error messages improve.

Comment: "Without the argument, there is no way to determine which instance should be used" Of course (slap forehead)! Thanks.